# Facebook key hashes generating wrong format

Tags: android, facebook

Im trying to generate a release key hash for an Android app with facebook connect.

When i run

```
keytool -exportcert -alias al1 -keystore "C:\Users\Chris\.android\debug.keystore" | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

It generates

```
Pz80cT8/PyE/PxQ/Pz9QPz8/Pz8K
```

But according to the Facebook form it should have no characters and have a trailing = sign.

When i copy and paste it gives an error

Edit - Add image error. This key is different to the one being generated by the answer

Key generated is Bc0k73mIke+DkZ7U6l3Y6+6FX3w= but the image shows different

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use below code for generating hash key ***(Using Function)***:

```
public static void printHashKey(Context pContext) {
    try {
        PackageInfo info = pContext.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(pContext.getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
        for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
            md.update(signature.toByteArray());
            String hashKey = new String(Base64.encode(md.digest(), 0));
            Log.i(TAG, "printHashKey() Hash Key: " + hashKey);
        }
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "printHashKey()", e);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "printHashKey()", e);
    }
}
```

After generating this hash key add this key into the facebook console.
after that you are able to access facebook.
***Using Command***

and for release key generate follow below steps:
***(For Windows User Only):***

```
Run the following command in a command prompt in the Java SDK folder:

keytool -exportcert -alias <RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS> -keystore <RELEASE_KEY_PATH> | PATH_TO_OPENSSL_LIBRARY\bin\openssl sha1 -binary | PATH_TO_OPENSSL_LIBRARY\bin\openssl base64
```

use this command and for download SSL [Use this link](https://code.google.com/archive/p/openssl-for-windows/downloads)

 ***(for the MAC User Only:)***

```
keytool -exportcert -alias <RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS> -keystore <RELEASE_KEY_PATH> | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

Comment: Does that generate Release key or Debug Key?

Comment: this key work for both for debug and for release aslo

Comment: Why is it not the same key that it shows in the error as not existing? Ill add a screenshot

Comment: I think problem is here:

keytool -exportcert -alias ***androiddebugkey*** -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore 
| openssl sha1 -binary
| openssl base64

you didn't write android debug key. so it may generate different key

Comment: Pz8RGD8HPz85d0Q/GQc/QWAPGD8K is generated which has the wrong format

Comment: keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "C:\Users\Chris\.android\debug.keystore" | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64

Comment: this key is generated using above answer? ***Pz8RGD8HPz85d0Q/GQc/QWAPGD8K***

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172390/discussion-between-mahesh-keshvala-and-user237462).

Comment: I was using the debug variant instead of release variant